# Unknown type error in C++ when I return Node *

Tags: c++, linked-list

When I compile, I got " error: unknown type name 'Node'"

It comes from *Node * findKthElementToLast(int k)* function since it returns Node * type

I am not able to solve it. Any help would be nice!

***LinkedList.h***

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class DataType>
class LinkedList{

struct Node {
    DataType dataIn;
    Node * next;
};

public:
    LinkedList();
   ~LinkedList();
    bool insertHead(DataType dataNew);
    bool insertTail(DataType dataNew);
    bool removeHead();
    bool removeTail();
    bool remove(DataType dataOut);
    bool removeDuplicates();
    bool removeDuplicatesUsingHash();
    bool search(DataType dataSearch);
    Node * findKthElementToLast(int k);
    void printLinkedList();

private:
   Node * head;

};
#endif
```

**findKthElementToLast function from LinkedList.cpp**

```
template<class DataType>
Node * LinkedList<DataType>::findKthElementToLast(int k){

    if(head == NULL){
     return head;
    } 
    Node * iter1 = head;
    Node * iter2 = head;

    int counter = 1;

    while(counter < k){
        counter++;
        iter2 = iter2->next;
    }
    while(iter2->next != NULL){
        iter1 = iter1->next;
        iter2 = iter2->next;
    }  
    return iter1;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
template<class DataType>
LinkedList<DataType>::Node *LinkedList<DataType>::findKthElementToLast(int k) {
```

Node is declared inside the LinkedList class, so any references from outside that class must be qualified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did this and it worked:     typename LinkedList<DataType>:: Node * LinkedList<DataType>::findKthElementToLast(int k)

Comment: Is there any more easy way to handle it.

Comment: You could also do `template<class DataType> auto LinkedList<DataType>::findKthElementToLast(int k) -> Node* {...}`, taking advantage of the fact that a trailing return type is in the class scope.

Comment: @grahamScan Sorry, i forgot the need for typename.